# disable systemType UIButton w/o gray out

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have several buttons in a mainMenu in my app. The menu works like a masterDetailMenu, but I created it myself. I change the image of the buttons (system buttons) with the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[_myButton setImage:myButtonActiveImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:_myButton];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To avoid UI bugs I want to disable `myButton` as long as it is active. But when I use `_myButton.enabled = NO;` it grays out the button.
I know that if the button was `custom` then I would not have the problem, even though I let it be a `system` button so it turns dark while pressed.

Does anyone have an idea how I can tell the button not to turn gray if it is inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I did not know there was a `UIControlStateDisabled`, therefore I just set the image to `myButtonActiveImage` and the button does not gray out anymore.